# ImportError while importing sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.7, importerror

I am using python 3.7
Recently I started getting this error while importing sklearn module.
I get the same error in Jupyter Notebook, Python IDLE, Pycharm virtual environment

```
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
  File "C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_show_versions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._openmp_helpers import _openmp_parallelism_enabled
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried reinstalling too. 
After that I copied contents of sklearn of venv of another project which had no issues. This thing worked for couple of times. But now it's not working again

Note: pandas, numpy, scipy etc are installed and working absolutely fine. Sklearn was also working fine few days back

Comment: How about installing an older version of sklearn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue in the packaging in scikit-learn 0.22.0 which will be solved in 0.22.1 (released next week). The issue is tracked at: github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15899. There are 2 possible workarounds:

- Install scikit-learn from conda-forge (conda include the missing dll) by default: `conda install conda-forge::scikit-learn`
- Install VC++ which will have the openmp library (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)